# Express server and socket.io not working in same port

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, port

### Not working can't find any issue in code##

> If I put any port number instead of server it's working but why didn't it's working with socket server anyone explain
> *I tried some solution but none of them work I want to run socket.io and express on same port number*

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require("cors");
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const http = require('http');
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const passport = require("passport");
const authRoute = require('./routes/auth');
const userRoute = require('./routes/user');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9000;
const db = require('./config/mongoose');
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use(passport.initialize());
require("./config/passport")(passport);

app.use(express.json());
app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/user", passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),userRoute);

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')
{
    app.use(express.static('client/build'))
}
```

**Here is the issue if I switch server to any port number it's fine**

```
const io = socketIO(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: '*',
    }
});
let state = {};
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    const { id } = socket.client;
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('socket disconnected!');
    });
    socket.on('join_room', function (data) {
        console.log('joining request rec.', data);

        socket.join(data.room);

        io.in(data.room).emit('user_joined', data);
    });
    socket.on('send_code', function (data) {
        io.in(data.room).emit('receive_code', data);
    });
});

app.listen(PORT, function (err) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(`Server is up and running on port: ${PORT}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http.createServer(app)` and `app.listen()` are not compatible as they both try to do the same thing.  If you look at the source code for `app.listen()`, you will see this:

```
app.listen = function listen() {
  var server = http.createServer(this);
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```

So, it's creating a DIFFERENT server object.  You end up with two and the first one never gets started so when you give it to socket.io, it never works.

Instead, remove this:

```
const server = http.createServer(app);
```

And, use this instead:

```
const server = app.listen(PORT, function (err) { ...});
```

This way, your `server` variable will contain the one and only server object that is actually running.

---

Alternatively, you could remove the `app.listen()` and then just add this in it's place:

```
server.listen(PORT, ...);
```

---

The general idea is that you want this pair:

```
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(PORT, ...);
```

Or, just this:

```
const server = app.listen(PORT, ...);
```

You cannot use both.  Either way, that `server` object will represent the server that is actually running and will work with socket.io.